# Adding library to my android project from github

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, lib

There is a lib by tatocaster https://github.com/tatocaster/StepView. And I have failed importing it. 
✓ Added dependency; 
✓ Added maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

But I get an error on layout: **'Cannot resolve class me.tatocaster.stepview.StepView'** 
By rebuilding the project I receive:

```
Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/tatocaster/StepView/1.0.0/StepView-1.0.0.pom'.
Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized 
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

I turn off and turn on offline mode in gradle, but it doesn't solve anything. 
Is this problem in me? How can I fix errors?

Answer (score 0):

https://jitpack.io/com/github/tatocaster/StepView/1.0.0/ requires a username and password to access the repo, hit this on your browser you'll see it's protected - so your app can't pull this repo via the link your hitting;

Add the dependency to Gradle per implementation instructions here: https://github.com/tatocaster/StepView

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.tatocaster:StepView:1.0.0'
    }
```

Sync your project and you should be able to to use StepView through your project; follow the instructions per the repo above it's pretty straight forward; the .pom in the URL you posted isn't accessible without creds; use Implementation instead.

Comment: But I added the dependency from the beginning.

Comment: You've added the implementation call for com.github.tatocaster:StepView:1.0.0? The sample project @ git shows this fairly simple to integrate, I'm unsure where you got that link that requires auth; your error exists only because your accessing a URL for this repo that you didn't supply creds; the implementation on the repo for StepView doesn't show it needs any creds; thinking you should try and resync @ follow steps in the repo

Comment: I have just created new project and copied all stuffs exactly from readme. But I got the same output. Error 401. Maybe the problem is in library?

Comment: Possibly, I've never used this one - Check this one out: https://pub.dev/packages/im_stepper